# Loading MNIST Dataset into Octave

Tags: io, octave

I am currently looking to dip my toes into deep learning after a few weeks reading some books and doing some more basic machine learning code. I found the MNIST digit database here http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ and am currently trying to determine how to actually use the data.

The data appears to be saved in the IDX3 format, of which I am completely unfamiliar.

I have the training and test data sets saved as text files, but that seems to be fairly useless. For some reason, when I try to load them into Octave using the fopen command, the result is simply '-1'

Does anyone know of the correct way to load this data into Octave? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does this code work in Octave?

https://github.com/davidstutz/matlab-mnist-two-layer-perceptron/blob/master/loadMNISTImages.m

Note that is `fopen` returns -1, then maybe the file path is not correct.

Comment: Yes, that code works. It take the MNIST file as input and returns a matrix where each row is the grayscale pixel values of a particular image. I posted that link before because I thought it would be useful for anyone who stumbled upon this thread, but a mod removed it.